# $\phi: G\to G'$ be a group homomorphism, is it true that $G/\ker\phi\cong G$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $\phi: G\to G'$ be a group homomorphism and $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. If $N=\ker\phi$, then is it true that $G/N\cong G$? That is, is it true that $G/N$ is isomorphic to $G$?

Furthermore, is it true that $G/N=G$?

I think both are true but not entirely sure why. Thanks.

Comment: Are you meaning $G'$ in various places?  For instance, $G/N$ isomorphic to $G'$?  (See the First Isomorphism Theorem, by the way.)

Comment: If you meant $G/N$ is isomorphic to $G'$ then this is true (first homomorphism theorem). It is not true that $G/N$ is equal to $G'$ even if $N=\{0\}$, unless we have chosen $G'=G/N$. Elements of $G/N$ are cosets of $N$, i.e. subsets of $G$.

Comment: @SamM this is still only true if $\phi$ is surjective.

Comment: Ah yes, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

If $\phi:0\not\cong G\rightarrow G'$ such that $\phi(g)=0$, then $\ker\phi=G$ and $G/\ker\phi\cong 0\not\cong G.$

Answer (score 0):

Even if $G≅G/N$, considering $G$ and $G/N$ as sets, $G/N ⊂ \mathcal{P}(G)$ so $G≠ G/N$.